# dcast error: `Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L)`

Tags: r, dcast

I have a dataframe called `df` that looks something like this...

```
"ID","ReleaseYear","CriticPlayerPrefer","n","CountCriticScores","CountUserScores"
"1",1994,"Both",1,5,283
"2",1994,"Critics",0,0,0
"3",1994,"Players",0,0,0
"4",1995,"Both",3,17,506
"5",1995,"Critics",0,0,0
"6",1995,"Players",0,0,0
"7",1996,"Both",18,163,3536
"8",1996,"Critics",2,18,97
"9",1996,"Players",3,20,79
```

I want to flip the data frame around so the columns are like this:

`"ReleaseYear","Both","Critics","Players"`

The values for columns `Both',`Critics`and`Players`would be the`n` for each.

When I try running this...

```
require(dcast)
chartData.CriticPlayerPreferByYear <- dcast(
    data = df,
    formula = ReleaseYear ~ CriticPlayerPrefer,
    fill = 0,
    value.var = n
)
```

... I get this error:

```
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
  'match' requires vector arguments
```

What is the problem here? How do I fix it?

Comment: `value.var = "n"`, the column name needs to be quoted.

Comment: dcast isn't a package, AFAIK; do you mean reshape2? An alternative: `library(dplyr) ; library(tidyr) ; df %>% select(ReleaseYear, CriticPlayerPrefer, n) %>% spread(CriticPlayerPrefer, n)`

Comment: @Psidom if you want me to mark this correct, go ahead and post your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be missing quotation marks?

```
data <- read.table(text='"ID","ReleaseYear","CriticPlayerPrefer","n","CountCriticScores","CountUserScores"
"1",1994,"Both",1,5,283
"2",1994,"Critics",0,0,0
"3",1994,"Players",0,0,0
"4",1995,"Both",3,17,506
"5",1995,"Critics",0,0,0
"6",1995,"Players",0,0,0
"7",1996,"Both",18,163,3536
"8",1996,"Critics",2,18,97
"9",1996,"Players",3,20,79"',header=T,sep=",")

library(reshape2)
dcast(data, ReleaseYear ~ CriticPlayerPrefer, value.var="n")

# ReleaseYear Both Critics Players
#       1994    1       0       0
#       1995    3       0       0
#       1996   18       2       3
```

This is what I get. Is it the desired result?

Comment: Just saw @Psidom comment; Ignore^